# How I use return inside a recursive functions in php

Tags: php, function, recursion

I have a php recursive function as shown in the below:

```
function displayDropdown(&$catList, $parent,  $current=[], $level=0) {
  if ($parent==0) {
    foreach ($catList[$parent] as $catID=>$nm) {
      displayDropdown($catList, $catID, $current);
    }
  }
  else {        
    foreach ($catList[$parent] as $catID=>$nm) {
      $sel = (in_array($catID, $current)) ? " selected = 'selected'" : '';       
      
      echo "<option value='$catID' $sel>$nm</option>\n";        
      
      if (isset($catList[$catID])) {
        displayDropdown($catList, $catID, $current, $level+1); 
      }
    }
  }   
}
```

This function is working for me. but I want to get output from a variable instead of echoing inside the function. Actually I need to `return` option list from the funciton.

This is how I tried it, but it doesn't work for me.

```
function displayDropdown(&$catList, $parent,  $current=[], $level=0) {
  $optionsHTML = '';
  if ($parent==0) {
    foreach ($catList[$parent] as $catID=>$nm) {
      displayDropdown($catList, $catID, $current);
    }
  }
  else {        
    foreach ($catList[$parent] as $catID=>$nm) {
      $sel = (in_array($catID, $current)) ? " selected = 'selected'" : '';       

      $optionsHTML .= "<option value='$catID' $sel>$nm</option>\n";        
      
      if (isset($catList[$catID])) {
        displayDropdown($catList, $catID, $current, $level+1);
      }
    }
  } 

  //return displayDropdown($optionsHTML);
  return $optionsHTML;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
This is how I call this function.

```
displayDropdown($catList, 0, [$cid])
```

This is how I create `$catList` array inside while loop with the result of a query.

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {    
  $catList[$parent][$catID] = $name;    
}
```

Array structure as below:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Uncategorized
            [3] => SHOW ITEMS
            [4] => HORN
            [5] => SWITCH
            [6] => LIGHT
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Products
        )
)
1
```

Hope somebody may help me out.

Comment: Calls to `displayDropdown(...);` should be `return displayDropdown(...);`.

Comment: @kmoser, you mean `return displayDropdown($optionsHTML);`?

Comment: I haven't read your code closely but generally calls to recursive functions should `return` the result of that function call. You haven't provided an example of the arguments passed to `displayDropdown()` so it's hard to say how it should work.

Comment: @kmoser this is how I the function `displayDropdown($catList, 0, [$cid])`

Comment: What are sample values in `$catList` and `$cid`? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72237225/edit) to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue.

Comment: This is how I create `catList` array from a query result  inside while loop `$catList[$parent][$catID] = $name;`

Comment: `$cid` have category ids. It may have single or multiple values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need also like this `$optionsHTML .= displayDropdown(...)`

```
function displayDropdown(&$catList, $parent,  $current=[], $level=0) {
  $optionsHTML = '';
  if ($parent==0) {
    foreach ($catList[$parent] as $catID=>$nm) {
      $optionsHTML .= displayDropdown($catList, $catID, $current);
    }
  }
  else {        
    foreach ($catList[$parent] as $catID=>$nm) {
      $sel = (in_array($catID, $current)) ? " selected = 'selected'" : '';       

      $optionsHTML .= "<option value='$catID' $sel>$nm</option>\n";        
      
      if (isset($catList[$catID])) {
        $optionsHTML .= displayDropdown($catList, $catID, $current, $level+1);
      }
    }
  } 

  return $optionsHTML;
}
```